# Get data from object child if it contains a certain string (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, string, loops

I am getting some data from an API (with JavaScript, the API is alphavantage.co) to get a stock dividends for a year. The API gives me the dividend per month. So what I need to do is sum the dividends from the child objects if they contain "2019".

The API looks like this:

```
"Monthly Adjusted Time Series": {
        "2019-12-31": {
            "1. open": "37.4800",
            "2. high": "39.4320",
            "3. low": "36.9050",
            "4. close": "38.9750",
            "5. adjusted close": "38.9750",
            "6. volume": "493073245",
            "7. dividend amount": "0.0000"
        },
        "2019-11-29": {
            "1. open": "38.9500",
            "2. high": "39.7000",
            "3. low": "36.4000",
            "4. close": "37.3800",
            "5. adjusted close": "37.3800",
            "6. volume": "605847809",
            "7. dividend amount": "0.0000"
        },
... And so on until year 2000
```

I understand I have to loop it, but how can I check if the child contains 2019? So it does not loop the other years?

Comment: Anything you've already tried out yourself?

Comment: I have tried to use a forEach loop but I am not getting anywere because I don't know how to write "if child contains "2019". So I am really stuck

Comment: But the object you pasted here is just incomplete. Just put proper braces around to let user know about the actual structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter out the values that don't match, then reduce on the result.

```js
Object.entries(monthlyAdjustedTimeSeries)
    // Remove items that don't contain 2019
    .filter(([k]) => k.includes("2019-"))
    // Get just the values
    .map(([_, v]) => parseFloat(v["7. dividend amount"]))
    // Sum
    .reduce((ac, v) => ac + v, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks, worked great. Just had to change "monthlyAdjutedTimeSeries" to data['Monthly Adjusted Time Series']

Comment: Hi again, the code works great but there is one thing I do not understand. Maybe it is a dumb question but I am trying to learn. What does the underscore do in the map function? This part: .map(([_, v])

Comment: The underscore is just a variable name that isn't being used. Starting a variable name with, or making the whole variable name, an underscore removes unused variable warnings from most linters.

Answer (score 1):

Let say, you got the main object containing other child objects for different years.

```js
    const data = {
            "2019-12-31": {
                "1. open": "37.4800",
                "2. high": "39.4320",
                "3. low": "36.9050",
                "4. close": "38.9750",
                "5. adjusted close": "38.9750",
                "6. volume": "493073245",
                "7. dividend amount": "0.0000"
            },
            "2019-11-29": {
                "1. open": "38.9500",
                "2. high": "39.7000",
                "3. low": "36.4000",
                "4. close": "37.3800",
                "5. adjusted close": "37.3800",
                "6. volume": "605847809",
                "7. dividend amount": "0.1000"
            }
            
       };
       
       const output = Object.keys(data).reduce((sum, key) => {
          if (key.indexOf('2019') > -1) {
            return sum + Number(data[key]['7. dividend amount']);
          }
          return sum;
       }, 0);
       
       console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a **[for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)** loop, with a **[RegExp.prototype.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)**

```
var data = [];
for(let e in obj["Monthly Adjusted Time Series"]) {
  if(/2019/.test(e)) {
    data.push(obj["Monthly Adjusted Time Series"][e]);
  }
}
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
Object.entries(obj).reduce((total, [key,])=>{
if(/2019/.test(key)) {
return total + +obj[key]["7. dividend amount"]
}},0);
```